# OGR error: Can't create field T4_3FTC in Shape DBF file after QGIS "Add geometry columns"

Tags: qgis, ogr, qgis-2, error

I have a shapefile with a relatively extensive attribute table. I extended it by adding geometry data ("Vector > Geometry tools > Export/Add geometry columns") and now I cannot save the layer in a new file. When I try to save it as an ESRI shapefile, I get a message:
*Export to vector file failed.
Error: creation of field T4_3FTC failed (OGR error: Can't create field T4_3FTC in Shape DBF file, reason unknown.)*

When I try to save it as a Geopackage file, I get a message:
*Export to vector file failed.
Error: creation of field fid failed (OGR error: Wrong field type for fid)*

When I try to save it as a CSV file, the program crashes and I lose my work (tried at least three times).

Apart from that, the file works perfectly, the attribute table isn't corrupted in any way. What should I do to fix the issue?

Edit: the program finally generated a CSV file after around 5 minutes of being unresponsive. Still no luck with other formats.

Comment: Might sound counter-productive but perhaps re-save the shapefile as a new shapefile, then export the geometry columns and re-save it again?

Comment: How many fields do you have in the .dbf file before you add new columns for the coordinates? Could you prepare a minimal sample for us with only one feature which has as many attributes and of the same kind that you have in your data?

Comment: @Joseph That's what I tried to do - saving after adding geometry columns fails as described.

Comment: @user30184 There are 790 fields (columns) in the table. Please find the complete table before adding geometry columns under the following link:
https://goo.gl/xRzJ9m

Comment: @JurekGozdek - Can't replicate your issue, this worked fine for me using QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit. Which version and for what platform are you using?

Comment: This mail may interest you https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-June/046747.html. It says that the DBF specification claims that maximum number of fields is 255 but in reality it is higher as you know because you are using such table. That can still have something to do with your problem.

Comment: similar pb, a workaround:  save as in GeoPackage format worked for me